# Why is everytime i select a new value in my select option, the value is duplicating or being called more

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select option. Everytime I am trying to change the set value for the option select, the value is duplicating.

here is the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var data_assessment = [];

  $('#sets_id').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    data_assessment = [];
    data_assessment = JSON.parse($("#sets_id option:selected").attr('data-category'));

    $("#first_category").click(function() {
      console.log(data_assessment)
    });

  });
});
```

```css
#first_category {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <select name="sets" id="sets_id">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Set</option>
    <option data-category="1" value="1">Set 1</option>
    <option data-category="2" value="2">Set 2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="first_category" class="category_icons">
</div>
```

The more I am choosing on the select tag, the value of `data_assessment` variable is duplicating :(. How can I fix this, I really don't know what to do.

Comment: You're adding an event handler inside another event handler. Adding a handler does not remove previously-added handlers. Thus over time there will be many redundant handlers, all doing the same thing.

Comment: How can i fix this sir? i really dont know what to do. :(

Comment: Move that "first_category" click handler assignment to *outside* of the "change" handler.

Comment: is  there a way a sir, that the click event will be inside on the change function event?

Comment: That makes no sense - read it again *"the click event inside the change event"*.  What are you trying to achieve by that?  It will work just as well outside.  If you must put it inside then remove old events first, eg `$("#id").off("click").click(...` - but this is a little "hacky"

Comment: i have 3 buttons sir, it is all unclickable if the user is still not choosing from the option, the buttons will be clickable based on what will be the data-attr of the select.

Comment: Ah - "clickable" and having a click event are 2 different things - either make it not-clickable eg `<button disabled>` (or `button { pointer-events: none; }`) then make it clickable when available - *or* make it "clickable" all the time and in the event handler itself check if it should do anything.

Comment: hi sir, thank you for this, i already solved my problem. thank you sir.